# How to put a new page on the stack from the Expo-Router tab bar

Tags: react-native, expo

I use several tabs in the bottom navigation bar to navigate between the main screens of the app. I also have an "Add" button in the middle of the bar as a tab icon.

Of course, when I press the "Add" tab bar icon, no new screen is added to the stack. The navigation bar remains visible and no "Back" button is created in the header menu bar.

Is there any way I can put a new screen on the stack from the tab bar similar to `router.push()`?

**app/_layout.tsx**

```
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)"/>
        </Stack>
    );
}
```

**app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx**

```
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <Tabs>
            <Tabs.Screen ... />
            <Tabs.Screen ... />
            <Tabs.Screen
                name="editor"
                options={{
                    title: "editor",
                    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', top: 0}}>
                                <AddIcon width={20} height={20} fill={focused ? "#5843A9" : "#fff"}/>
                            </View>
                        );
                    },
                    tabBarButton: (props) => (
                        <CustomTabBarButton onPress={props.onPress} children={props.children}/>
                    ),
                }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen ... />
            <Tabs.Screen ... />
        </Tabs>
    );
}
```